# import package statement not working

Tags: java

I am trying to import a package into another project. Just to be clear, I am using NetBeans and all my projects are located in the same folder. 
So, I have a package called **createobjectdemo**, and I am trying to import it into another project called **valueOfDemo**. 
The statement that I am using is:
import createobjectdemo.*;
This line invokes the error: package createobjectdemo does not exit. 
But... it does exist! It is located in the same folder hosting all my Java projects. I have it open right now in the NetBeans editor window.

Why can't I access the package? Do I have to provide a specific path? Sorry, this has got to be really simple, but I can't figure it out. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read up on the `classpath` and how to set it up in Netbeans.

Comment: try to write the full path to the package, that would be a good start and of course read on the "classpath"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `.jar` file of java files which you want to use in another project and add your project in menu **Libraries** to another project.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how your projects are set up makes it difficult to answer your question.  I imagine your setup is something like the following:

```
projects/
  project_1/
    src/        // Or maybe you have src/ and classes/ in the same directory
      createobjectdemo/
        CreateObject.java
    classes/
      createobjectdemo/
        CreateObject.class
  project_2/
    src
      valueOfDemo/
        ValueOf.java
    classes/
      valueOfDemo/
        ValueOf.class
```

So, the package exists but it's not in your class path.  You can tell NetBeans (I have no experience with it, but I'm sure you can) that you want `project1`'s `classes` directory added to your build path, or possibly just add the first project to the build path, and NetBeans can figure out where to find the compiled classes.

Remember, each file in a package must declare that's it's in that package; otherwise, it just happens to be in that directory but (if the directory is on the classpath), it's in the "default" package, and can't be imported by package name.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. Will read on classpath and Jar files and everything else. I am a total beginner so I just had the wrong impression that I could import a package from another project just as easily as importing a package from the Java API. Little disappointed now, but I'll get over it.

Comment: Ok, it works now. Thanks again. In case anybody has the same issue: to import a package from another project, right click on the current project in the Projects window, select Properties, then Libraries, then use the Add JAR/Folder button to add the project containing the package you want to import.

Comment: By the way, welcome to SO.  Read the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to get some tips on how to use the site.  You can use up-votes (and accept answers) to show appreciation, too.